# Sumo Logic kubernetes integration requires that no Prometheus exists

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, newrelic, amazon-eks, sumologic

I am currently working on integrating **Sumo Logic** in a **AWS EKS** cluster. After going through **Sumo Logic**'s documentation on their integration with k8s I have arrived at the following section [Installation Steps](https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumologic-kubernetes-collection/blob/master/deploy/docs/Installation_with_Helm.md#installation-steps). This section of the documentation is a fork in the road where one must figure out if you want to continue with the installation :

- side by side with your existing Prometheus Operator
- and update your existing Prometheus Operator
- with your standalone Prometheus (not using Prometheus Operator)
- with no pre-existing Prometheus installation

With that said I am trying to figure out which scenario I am in as I am unsure.
Let me explain, previous to working on this Sumo Logic integration I have completed the [New Relic integration](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/integrations/kubernetes-integration/installation/kubernetes-integration-install-configure#configure-the-integration) which makes me wonder if it uses Prometheus in any ways that could interfere with the Sumo Logic integration ?

So in order to figure that out I started by executing:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                                      READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
aws-alb-ingress-controller-1600289507-7c7dc6f57d-sgpd8    1/1     Running     1          7d19h
f5-admin-ui-5cbcc464df-lh8nl                              1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-ambassador-5b5db5ff88-k5clw                            1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-api-gateway-7bdfc9cb-q57lt                             1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-argo-ui-7b98dd67-2cwrz                                 1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-auth-ui-58794664d9-rbccn                               1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-classic-rest-service-0                                 1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-connector-plugin-service-box-7f8b48b88-8jxxq           1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-connector-plugin-service-ldap-5d79fd4b8b-8kpcj         1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-connector-plugin-service-sharepoint-77b5bdbf9b-vqx4t   1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-devops-ui-859c97fb97-ftdxh                             1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-fusion-admin-64fb9df99f-svznw                          1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-fusion-indexing-6bbc7d4bcd-jh7cf                       1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-fusion-log-forwarder-78686cb8-shd6p                    1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-insights-6d9795f57-62qbg                               1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-job-launcher-9b659d984-n7h65                           1/1     Running     3          7d19h
f5-job-rest-server-55586d8db-xrzcn                        1/1     Running     2          7d19h
f5-ml-model-service-6c5bfd5b68-wwdkq                      2/2     Running     0          7d19h
f5-pm-ui-cc64c9498-gdmvp                                  1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-pulsar-bookkeeper-0                                    1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-pulsar-bookkeeper-1                                    1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-pulsar-bookkeeper-2                                    1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-pulsar-broker-0                                        1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-pulsar-broker-1                                        1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-query-pipeline-84749b6b65-9hzcx                        1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-rest-service-7855fdb676-6s6n8                          1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-rpc-service-676bfbf7f-nmbgp                            1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-rules-ui-6677475b8b-vbhcj                              1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-solr-0                                                 1/1     Running     0          20h
f5-templating-b6b964cdb-l4vjq                             1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-webapps-798b4d6864-b92wt                               1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-workflow-controller-7447466c89-pzpqk                   1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-zookeeper-0                                            1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-zookeeper-1                                            1/1     Running     0          7d19h
f5-zookeeper-2                                            1/1     Running     0          7d19h
nri-bundle-kube-state-metrics-cdc9ffd85-2s688             1/1     Running     0          2d21h
nri-bundle-newrelic-infrastructure-fj9g9                  1/1     Running     0          2d21h
nri-bundle-newrelic-infrastructure-jgckv                  1/1     Running     0          2d21h
nri-bundle-newrelic-infrastructure-pv27n                  1/1     Running     0          2d21h
nri-bundle-newrelic-logging-694hl                         1/1     Running     0          2d21h
nri-bundle-newrelic-logging-7w8cj                         1/1     Running     0          2d21h
nri-bundle-newrelic-logging-8gjw8                         1/1     Running     0          2d21h
nri-bundle-nri-kube-events-865664658d-ztq89               2/2     Running     0          2d21h
nri-bundle-nri-metadata-injection-557855f78d-rzjxd        1/1     Running     0          2d21h
nri-bundle-nri-metadata-injection-job-cxmqg               0/1     Completed   0          2d21h
nri-bundle-nri-prometheus-ccd7b7fbd-2npvn                 1/1     Running     0          2d21h
seldon-controller-manager-5b5f89545-6vxgf                 1/1     Running     1          7d19h
```

As you can see New Relic is running `nri-bundle-nri-prometheus-ccd7b7fbd-2npvn` which seems to correspond to the New Relic OpenMetric integration for Kubernetes or Docker. Browsing through New Relic's [documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/integrations/prometheus-integrations/get-started/send-prometheus-metric-data-new-relic) I found:

> We currently offer two integration options:
>
> - Prometheus remote write integration. Use this if you currently have
>   Prometheus servers and want an easy access to your combined metrics
>   from New Relic.
> - Prometheus OpenMetrics integration for Kubernetes or
>   Docker. Use this if you’re looking for an alternative or replacement
>   to a Prometheus server and store all your metrics directly in New
>   Relic.

So from what I can gather I am not running **Prometheus** *server* or *operator* and I can continue with the Sumo Logic integration setup by following the section dedicated to *installation with no pre-existing Prometheus installation* ? This is what I am trying to clarify, wondering if someone can help as I am new to **Kubernetes** and **Prometheus**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I followed the Sumo Logic integration instructions dedicated to a setup with no pre-existing Prometheus installation and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you most likely will have to go with the below installation option :

- with your standalone Prometheus (not using Prometheus Operator)

Can you check and paste the output of `kubectl get prometheus`. If you see any running prometheus, you can run `kubectl describe prometheus $prometheus_resource_name` and check the labels to verify if it is deployed by the operator or it is a standalone prometheus.

In case it is deployed by Prometheus operator, you can use either of these approaches:

- side by side with your existing Prometheus Operator
- update your existing Prometheus Operator

Comment: Vijit when I do :
kubectl get prometheus I get the following error:
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "prometheus" does that mean there is no pre-existing Prometheus installation at all ? Was not aware that "prometheus" was a resource type.